# Javascript, setting timeout between events in one function

Tags: javascript, timing

lets say I have a function in a loop that will display two different kinds of text interchangeably over and over.

Now what I want to achive is for the different text to be displayed with a delay, let's say 1 second. So it would print 1st text and after 1 second 2nd text and so on untill the loop is over. I was trying to use `setTimeout` and `setInterval` but I cannot get it to work.

```js
var a = "hey ";
var b = "ho ";

function test(a,b){
  document.getElementById('id').innerHTML += a;
  document.getElementById('id').innerHTML += b;
 }

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
 setInterval(test(a,b), 1000);
}
```

```html
<div id="id">

</div>
```

Comment: To be clear you want it to print hey, then clear that and print ho, then clear that and print hey again - every second for 10 seconds.... or something else?

Comment: yes that's exactly what I want to do

Comment: Yet you mark as an answer one which does something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You need to use `setTimeout` to introduce delay and not setInterval.
- Timeout should be in incremental order so multiply it with `i`
- `test(a,b)` should be in callback of the function so that setTimeout can execute it based on the delay. If you will directly write `test(a,b)` then it will get executed right then and there without any delay.

```js
var a = "hey ";
var b = "ho ";

function test(a,b){
  document.getElementById('id').innerHTML += a;
  setTimeout(function(){
     document.getElementById('id').innerHTML += b;
  }, 500)
 }

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
 setTimeout(function(){
  test(a,b);
 }, i*1000);
}
```

```html
<div id="id">

</div>
```

**UPDATE**

Delay between `document.getElementById('id')`

Comment: That helps a bit, but I'd want the delay to be between "hey" and "ho" also, not only between "hey ho".

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `setInterval` and keep track of how many were done with a variable :

```js
var count = 0; //Variable to keep track of the number of setInterval called
var text = ['text1','text2'];

var interval = setInterval(() => {
  if(count == 10) clearInterval(interval); //Stop the setInterval when you reach the 10th time
  document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = count % 2 == 0 ? text[0] : text[1];
  count++; //Increment your var
},1000);
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an "asynchonous" loop for this, i.e. a function that calls itself after a time out. Then use the modulo operator to decide whether to show `a` or `b`:

```js
var a = "hey ";
var b = "ho ";

function test(c){
    document.getElementById('id').innerHTML += c;
}

(function loop(i){
    if (i >= 10) return; // All done
    test(i%2 ? b : a); // choose which one to show
    setTimeout(loop.bind(null, i+1), 1000); // Repeat with delay and incremented i.
})(0); // Start the loop immediately with i=0
```

```html
<div id="id">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function loop(i, limit) {  
  if (i < limit) {
    console.log('Text 1');
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('Text 2');      
      setTimeout(function() {
        loop(++i,limit);
      },1000);
    },1000);
  }
}

loop(0,3);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your code around a bit to introduce a delay between each.

The code below:

- stores the possible values in the array
- has a method which will `display` the `i`th element from the values
- has a `run` method used to start the loop, and also recalled with a delay (1second) having incremented a counter

```js
var values = ["hey","ho"];
var index = 0;

function display(i){
  document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = values[i];
}

function run(){
    display(index%values.length)
    if(++index<10){
      setTimeout(run,1000);
    }
}

run();
```

```html
<div id="id">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the timeout between 'hey' and 'ho' also, you shouldn't be keeping both of them inside `test`, instead keep only one and change the param value.

```js
var a = "hey ";
var b = "ho ";

function test(a){
  document.getElementById('id').innerHTML += a;
 }

for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
 (function(i) {
   setTimeout(function(){
    test(i % 2 === 0 ? a : b);
   }, i*1000);
 }(i))
}
```

```html
<div id="id">

</div>
```

Comment: I had to use a closure there because `i` value will be 10 when `setTimeout` starts executing.